# Issue with Go module cache creation: "mkdir C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe: The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: go

first I want to make it known I'm a pretty inexperienced developer, so I hope I'm just doing something that's an easy fix but I cant find anything anywhere with a solution that works for me.

I'm encountering a problem with my Go setup, and I have no idea what's causing it. When I try to execute "go run main.go" in the Visual Studio Code terminal, I get the following error message:

`go: could not create module cache: mkdir C:\\Program Files\\Go\\bin\\go.exe: The system cannot find the path specified.`

I'm using latest Go version (1.21.1) on a Windows 10 machine. Here are the details of my setup:
GOPATH is set to C:\Users\Cobra\OneDrive\Documents\Go
GOROOT is set to C:\Program Files\Go
GO111MODULE is set to on
I'm running Visual Studio Code

My go env:

```
set GO111MODULE=on
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Cobra\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\Cobra\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLCHAIN=auto
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.21.1
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
set GOMOD=C:\Users\Cobra\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=C:\Users\Cobra\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2381110002=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

I've tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but none of them have worked so far:

Checked that GOPATH and GOROOT are correct.
Edited file permissions for the directory C:\Program Files\Go\bin
Restarted VSCode and my computer.
Ensured that my Go/VSCode/Git/Windows installation is up to date.

I think there may be an issue with my environment or configuration settings. Can anyone help me find the root cause of this error and suggest a solution? Any guidance would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: @HoborMallow I added my go environment settings, I hope this helps

Comment: GOMODCACHE ist set tot a totally crap value. Just do not set _any_ of these variables (especially without understanding what they do). You also say "Checked that GOPATH and GOROOT are correct". No they are **not** correct. You should not set GOPATH at all. Stop consulting every resource that even talks about GOPATH. Just unset your GOPATH and you should be good to go.

Comment: Volker means that there indeed were times (very long gone) where you needed to tweak GOROOT after installing Go, and there were times (long gone) where you needed to set GOPATH to work with source code writtein in Go–both your own and third party. These times are gone, and any sensible Go version you can reasonably use these days does not require setting any of the environment variables. You _can_ of course tweak _some_ of them but this is not required for Go to operate properly and may have adverse effect if set incorrectly (your case).

Comment: So, please, remove all the `GO*` variables you have set, reboot and verify (using `go env` and other means) that they are unset (`go env` will show "sensible defaults" in this case). Everything will work OK then.